# Equivalent of {{#with}} in angular

Tags: angularjs, handlebars.js

What's the equivalent to `{{#with}}` in handlebars in angular? I'd like to create a sub scope with data from the result of a method call.

For example, I'd imagine it would be something like this (which obviously isn't correct):

```
<div ng-with="getData(myData)">{{name}}</div>
```

With `myData` as a value on the parent scope and `name` a property on the returned object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make your own

```
module.directive("ngWith", function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            var result = scope.$parent.$eval(attr.ngWith);
            for (var prop in result) {
                if (result.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    scope[prop] = result[prop];
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

in markup

```
<div ng-with="getData(myData)">{{name}}</div>
```

The expression inside the ng-with attribute is evaluated against the parent scope, each property in the return value will be binded to the new child scope created by the directive, under the same name.

I don't think there is much use for this directive though. If you just want to display the name property, just do `{{getData(myData)['name']}}` or save the result of the function to a scope variable