# Is there any directive that acts like a "with" in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Say you have an object yourObject on the scope and you want to access some deep properties like the following :

```
<ol>
 <li ng-bind="yourObject.thing.map.one"></li>
 <li ng-bind="yourObject.thing.map.two"></li>
 <li ng-bind="yourObject.thing.map.three"></li>
</ol>
```

Is there any built-in directive that could make it look more like this:

```
<ol ng-with="yourObject.thing.map">
 <li ng-bind="one"></li>
 <li ng-bind="two"></li>
 <li ng-bind="three"></li>
</ol>
```

**UPDATE**
A similar question was already. Please see [Equivalent of {{#with}} in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131910/equivalent-of-with-in-angular)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equivalent of {{#with}} in angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131910/equivalent-of-with-in-angular)

Answer (score 1):

One way I would do this scenario is by implementing a controller that will have a variables to those an array of one, two three... and then using `ng-repeat` to loop over that.

So for `ng-controller`, you could write, `ng-controller="SomeCtrl as ctrl"`

and then `ctrl.arrayVariable` would hold an array of all the data you want to show

To make matters very simple, you could use `ng-repeat` to loop through the data.
So, possibly, `ng-repeat="var in ctrl.arrayVariable"`

Anyways, I'm not sure exactly how your code is structured, but it should work in most instances.

Long story short, `ng-repeat` is awesome

Comment: Great idea and simple. I though I could spare myself yet more code but it seems your solution is the simplest. Thanks ! (note: though the example looks like a repeating pattern, I'm looking for a global solution to the deep-nested-properties-access-clutter problem)